# Is it possible to reference IdentityModel library in a project .Net framework 4.5?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, identitymodel

When I try to install the nuget package for IdentityModel for my .NET Framework 4.5 console application, I get the error:

```
Could not install package 'IdentityModel 3.10.10'. You are trying to install
this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the
package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are
compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

But it does work in my ASP.NET Web Application, which targets .NET Core 2.1.

Is it possible to use this library in a console application, or am I forced to use a web application?

Comment: Much more important, than if it’s a console or a web-app is, that it’s .Net Core and not.NetFramework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IdentityModel requires minimum .NETFramework 4.5.2 or NetStandard 2.0

https://www.nuget.org/packages/identitymodel/

Please see below 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: Worth noting that release 4.0.0 dropped support for net452, so if you're using 4.5.2, you'll need to install IdentityModel 3.10.10 or older.